# What layer does a UserControl's base class belong in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I have an asp.net usercontrol (ascx) that inherits from an abstract class (that inherits from a UserControl).  My Project is in a 3-tier architecture (DAL -> Bll -> UI/Views).  Currently there are no class files in the UI layer (other than the code-behinds).  Which layer should I add this abstract class to?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UserControl is part of your presentation, so should be in your UI/Views layer.

Think of it this way: *If I was re-implementing this as a Windows Forms application, which layers would I keep?* It'd be the DAL and BLL, therefore nothing specific to asp.net should be in either of those layers and the converse is: anything specific to asp.net should be in the UI/Views layer.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely presentation layer.  Ideally you don't want anything UI-dependant (such as the base UserControl class or anything from System.Web.UI) in your business logic.